Passing flag to InstallCommand of ExePackage doesn't work
I'm trying to itergrate elastic agent to the chain of my installer:
<ExePackage SourceFile="$(var.ThirdParty)\Installer\EA\elastic-agent.exe" InstallCommand="install" />

Above setup will run but the elastic-agent.exe will ask for some confirm like:
Elastic Agent will be installed at C:\Program Files\Elastic\Agent and will run as a service. Do you want to continue? [Y/n]:

So that I want to emit these questions, I tested with command like:
    .\elastic-agent.exe install -f
I see that it works:\elastic-agent.exe install -f
[=== ] Service Started  [11s] Elastic Agent successfully installed, starting enrollment.
[=== ] Done  [11s]
Elastic Agent has been successfully installed.

But when I try to pass the flg '-f' to InstallCommand, it doesn't work as expected
<ExePackage SourceFile="$(var.ThirdParty)\Installer\EA\elastic-agent.exe" InstallCommand="install -f" />

I get this error:
[5134:3824][2024-07-24T09:59:24]e000: Error 0x80070001: Process returned error: 0x1
[5134:3824][2024-07-24T09:59:24]e000: Error 0x80070001: Failed to execute EXE package.
[20F4:5A58][2024-07-24T09:59:24]e000: Error 0x80070001: Failed to configure per-machine EXE package.


When you added the command-line flag, it caused the process to start returning exit code 1. Exit codes are specific to the .exe you are running so you'll need to follow up with the vendor of the .exe to understand what 1 means.
Once you know the known exit codes, if they do not follow standard installer exit codes you can use the ExitCode element to instruct Burn how to interpret them.
